# Can I see why my question got a downvote?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, questions, specific-question, down-votes

My question got a downvote. Can I see somewhere why this happened?

This is my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19877894/error-with-pdo-query

Comment: Users are not required to explain downvotes (or upvotes), so no, it is not possible unless the downvoter also left a comment

Comment: [Encouraging people to explain downvotes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-downvotes)

Comment: Actually yes, you can see: hover your mouse in the down arrow, the tooltip explains why.

Answer (score 8):

No one knows why exactly a post got downvoted. In this case, however, it might have been an expression of discontent over your use of PDO, which is insecure because of its vulnerability to [SQL injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php). PDO can make querying safer, but only if prepared statements are used, see [this manual page.](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php)

However, adding that kind of advice as an answer is traditionally, sadly, discouraged by the community, as it doesn't technically answer the question. Vote-wise, Stack Overflow's dynamic often tends to favour the uninformed *literal* answer over the informed one that says "hey, you shouldn't be doing this in the first place."

Add to that that questions from newbies exposing bad database practices are very common on Stack Overflow (often coming from bad tutorials). With 7,000+ new questions a day, veterans of the site will feel a bit of burnout trying to address the same issues over and over. That's not to blame you as the question asker - it's a perfectly valid issue from your point of view. But you see the problem.

It is possibly out of frustration over these things that your question received a downvote. Never mind the vote, and move on.

Comment: One of these days they'll be as grumpy as the C++ folks. :)

Comment: I think that kind of advice as an answer **should** be discouraged - otherwise we may just end up with a bunch of "don't do it that way" answers (which would likely get more and more opinionated) without many *actual* answers. Adding a "you shouldn't be doing this in the first place" footnote to a literal answer would probably be the best of both worlds.

Comment: It is actually okay to say "don't do that" and then follow up with "try this instead". See the "Answer The Question" section of [answer]. When I answer in this manner, I still try to give the asker what he or she is looking for, as sometimes my assumptions about their problem are wrong since I'm not there with them to see the full picture.

Answer (score 3):

Given that nobody is obliged to explain their downvotes, there is not necessarily a way to find out why that happened to your question. If you are really confused about it however, you have some options:

Leave a constructive comment below your question asking for input. So not something like "Hey @downvoter, explain yourself", but more something along the lines of "I see I've received a downvote. Are there any concerns I could/should address? Is there anything I can do to make this question better?". With a bit of luck that will get you some comments from users (not necessarily the downvoters) on how to improve your question.

Or you could come to Meta and ask us to evaluate your question. Once again, come with a constructive attitude. No complaints, just a real interest in evaluating and improving your question. One word of warning though: coming to Meta might be a double-edged sword. It will drive traffic to your question. And additional views might mean additional votes. But a constructive approach will get you far.